# How do I center a fixed header and body text?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a small website, and I've figured out how to make a header and footer. The issue is, the header stops on the left side of the page and does not stop on the right. The footer stops in both direction. I want both the header and footer to reach the edges of the page. How do I do this? Additionally, how do I ensure body text is an equal distance from both the header and footer? Thanks!

```css
body {
  padding-top: 150px;
  /*dear god. save yourself. ALWAYS have padding you actual fool.>*/
  padding-bottom: 40px;
}

p {
  color: black;
  margin-left: 50px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: medium;
}

.fixed-header {
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
  font-size: large;
  top: 0;
}

.footer {
  bottom: 0;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 0%;
  background-color: black;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100px;
  /*set line height=height to center text vertically!*/
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
}

a:link,
a:visited,
a:hover,
a:active {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

nav a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 5px 35px 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 15%;
  height: auto;
}

a {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<DOCTYPE! html>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <html lang="en-US">

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css-attempt.css">
    <title>Hmm</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="fixed-header">
      <h1><a href="index.html">Hmm</a></h1>
      <div class="container">
        <nav>
          <a href="#">About</a>
          <a href="#">Resources</a>
          <a href="#">Projects</a>
          <a href="#">Connect</a>
          <a href="#">Donate</a>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>
    <p> Took way too long to understand why this text wasn't showing up. 6 hours of my life I'm never getting back.</p>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <p> Do you ever feel like a plastic bag?</p>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="footer">This is a footer. It's here because the content ends here.</div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

I've tried adjusting padding, margins, and basically everything I could think of, given I have maybe two weeks of experience with coding.

Comment: what do you mean the header does not stop on the right side of the page? Is the header not 100% the width of the page?

Comment: @ChrisHappy Essentially, the black background of my header appears to run off the edge of the screen on the right, but on the left, it ends a few pixels before the edge of the page, leaving a small white space on the left edge. The header should be 100% of the page, seeing as I've got the fixed-header class set to width 100%, but maybe I did something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your body has a margin from the user agent stylesheet.  Override this by setting margin to zero for the body.

```css
body {
  padding-top: 150px;
  /*dear god. save yourself. ALWAYS have padding you actual fool.>*/
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  margin: 0;
}

p {
  color: black;
  margin-left: 50px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: medium;
}

.fixed-header {
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
  font-size: large;
  top: 0;
}

.footer {
  bottom: 0;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 0%;
  background-color: black;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100px;
  /*set line height=height to center text vertically!*/
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
}

a:link,
a:visited,
a:hover,
a:active {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

nav a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 5px 35px 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 15%;
  height: auto;
}

a {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<DOCTYPE! html>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <html lang="en-US">

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css-attempt.css">
    <title>Hmm</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="fixed-header">
      <h1><a href="index.html">Hmm</a></h1>
      <div class="container">
        <nav>
          <a href="#">About</a>
          <a href="#">Resources</a>
          <a href="#">Projects</a>
          <a href="#">Connect</a>
          <a href="#">Donate</a>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>
    <p> Took way too long to understand why this text wasn't showing up. 6 hours of my life I'm never getting back.</p>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <p> Do you ever feel like a plastic bag?</p>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="footer">This is a footer. It's here because the content ends here.</div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

Comment: See "normalize CSS" for more information related to this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Here are 2 solutions provided. I believe, that 1st is what you really need, but the second solution is the case with default body margins saved.

```css
body {
    padding-top: 150px; /*dear god. save yourself. ALWAYS have padding you actual fool.>*/
    padding-bottom: 40px;
    margin: 0; /* <- just reset the margins */
}

p {
    color:black;
    margin-left: 50px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: medium;
}

.fixed-header {
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    background: black;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size: large;
    top: 0;
}

.footer {
    bottom: 0;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 0%;
    background-color: black;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 100px; /*set line height=height to center text vertically!*/
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
}

a:link, a:visited, a:hover, a:active {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.container {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

nav a {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 5px 35px 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 15%;
    height:auto;
}

a {
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<DOCTYPE! html>
<html lang="en-US">
  <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css-attempt.css">
      <title>Hmm</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  </head>
  <body>
      <div class="fixed-header">
        <div class="container">
        <h1><a href="index.html">Hmm</a></h1>
          <nav>
              <a href="#">About</a>
              <a href="#">Resources</a>
              <a href="#">Projects</a>
              <a href="#">Connect</a>
              <a href="#">Donate</a>
          </nav>
        </div>
      </div>
      <p> Took way too long to understand why this text wasn't showing up. 6
          hours of my life I'm never getting back.</p>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
     
      <p> Do you ever feel like a plastic bag?</p>
      <div class="container">
          <div class="footer">This is a footer. It's here because the content ends here.</div>        
      </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

```css
body {
        padding-top: 150px; /*dear god. save yourself. ALWAYS have padding you actual fool.>*/
        padding-bottom: 40px;
        margin: 10px; /* default margin */
    }

    p {
        color:black;
        margin-left: 50px;
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-size: medium;
    }

    .fixed-header {
        width: auto; /* <- the width of 100% equals to the width of the page here, but there is a margin of 10px of the body element from the left*/
        position: fixed;
        background: black;
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
        font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
        font-size: large;
        top: 0;
        left: 10px; /* <- */
        right: 10px; /* <- */
    }

    .footer {
        bottom: 0;
        height: 100px;
        width: 100%;
        padding-bottom: 0%;
        background-color: black;
        text-align: center;
        line-height: 100px; /*set line height=height to center text vertically!*/
        color: white;
        font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    }

    a:link, a:visited, a:hover, a:active {
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    .container {
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0;
    }

    nav a {
        color: #fff;
        text-decoration: none;
        padding: 5px 35px 10px;
        display: inline-block;
        width: 15%;
        height:auto;
    }

    a {
        color: white;
    }
```

```html
<DOCTYPE! html>
<html lang="en-US">
  <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css-attempt.css">
      <title>Hmm</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  </head>
  <body>
      <div class="fixed-header">
        <div class="container">
        <h1><a href="index.html">Hmm</a></h1>
          <nav>
              <a href="#">About</a>
              <a href="#">Resources</a>
              <a href="#">Projects</a>
              <a href="#">Connect</a>
              <a href="#">Donate</a>
          </nav>
        </div>
      </div>
      <p> Took way too long to understand why this text wasn't showing up. 6
          hours of my life I'm never getting back.</p>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>

      <p> Do you ever feel like a plastic bag?</p>
      <div class="container">
          <div class="footer">This is a footer. It's here because the content ends here.</div>        
      </div>
  </body>
</html>
```